# c# Panel subpanel and button

Tags: c#, .net, button, panel

I created some user controls to duplicate easily a standard button and 2 different panels

Let’s say:

```
The panel 1: p1 
       button B
The panel 2: p2 
       button B
```

Once my form is created, there is a B in p1 and a B in P2, as shown above. 
B needs to have an action if he is in p1 and another action if he is in p2

Do anyone knows if B can understand if he is in p1 or p2 ?

I already instanced p1 and p2 but it does not really change the fact that he catches or not he is inside the panel.

Comment: Let me clear some points 1.You are using web user control?2.)this user control contain only one button control ?.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. How can you have the same button in 2 different panels?

Can you paste a snippet of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work for you.For time being i am using single Button control in usercontrol :

**ASCX file :**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="buttonl.ascx.cs"Inherits="Controls_buttonl" %>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button user control" 
onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

**ASCX.cs file :**

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ID == "buttonl1")
    {
        //perform action according to panel1
    }
    else if (this.ID == "buttonl2")
    {
        //perform action according to panel2
    }
}
```

**ASPX page (Parentpage) :**

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>


    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="99px" Width="224px">
     <uc1:buttonl ID="buttonl1" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
<div>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="97px" Width="222px">
    <uc1:buttonl ID="buttonl2" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
```

Please let me know if still not able to reach your target.